# What is the recommended Nylon washer thickness, OD and ID for M2.5 screws?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am using two different M2.5 screws. One has head of diameter 4.5mm and the other has a head diameter of 4.75mm. If I want to use Nylon washer to distribute the load evenly, what is the recommended washer thickness, OD and ID for each type of screws?

Comment: Do you actually have a choice? Just buy ones off the shelf unless you have special requirements. The OD is chosen based on how much pressure you want on your substrate for your tightening force. Thickness again depends on the force desired and the washer material. ID is just chosen to be small enough to fit the screw but large enough so it goes on easily but you can technically get it real snug if you want to.

Comment: Actually there are many choices. Is the larger OD and thickness the less pressure on the surface?

Comment: Yes. Larger washer area and more thickness means less pressure on the substrate.

Comment: Thanks. I shall choose accordingly.